# Web mcv configurer for thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I use this configuration for my web configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.siarhei")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/");
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(5000000);
        return multipartResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(jsonConverter());
    }

    @Bean(name = "jacksonHttpMessageConverter")
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setPrettyPrint(true);
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.valueOf("application/json")));
        return converter;
    }
```

and it works but Now I found out about a standard configuration for thymeleaf which is this

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.valentine")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver (){
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        return resolver;
    }


    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine (){

        Set<IDialect> dialects = new HashSet<>();
        dialects.add(new LayoutDialect());

        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        engine.setAdditionalDialects(dialects);

        return engine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver(){
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setViewNames(new String[]{"," , "js/*" , "template/*"});
        return resolver;
    }
```

And this doesn't work work .

I am using thymeleaf , my question I why does the other configuration work for thymeleaf and this doesn't work?

Comment: You seem to have a discrepancy with your component scan annotation. Could you fix it and retry?

`@ComponentScan("com.valentine")`

Comment: Also, if you could explain what exactly is not working, someone could try to help.